# Is it possible to detect contact with every frame change when using an animation in SpriteKit?

Tags: collision-detection, ios, spritekit, xcode, swift

Is it possible to detect contact with every frame change when using an animation in SpriteKit? For example, if I have two nodes of a person walking, I want to detect contact with the ground each time the frame changes (the character is walking on a surface). Just can't seem to get it.

I've tried using a for loop to add a physics body and the contact and collision properties to each node, but that doesn't seem to work. It detects contact once, but that's it. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Person1` and `Person2` `SKPhysicsBody` a little smaller than the `SKSpriteNode`.

Then, add your `Person1` and `Person2` to update loop. You can do this by subclassing both `SKSpriteNode`s and then setting the `name` property to, for example, `person`. Implement a method in `Person1` and `Person2` that looks like this:

```
//Objective C
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime

//Swift
func update(_ currentTime: NSTimeInterval)
```

Then, in your `GameScene` - that already has an `update:` method- use this to call `Person1` and `Person2` update methods:

```
//Objective C
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"person" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    [(Person *)node update:currentTime];
}];

//Swift
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("person", usingBlock: {
    (node: SKNode!, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer <ObjCBool>) -> Void in 
    var person = node as? Person
    person.update(currentTime)
})
```

This will call `Persons update:` method each frame. Now we want to check in this `update:` if we are collisioning with the floor, for example, like this:

```
//Objective C
GameScene *parentScene = (GameScene *)self.parent;
if (CGRectIntersectsWithRect(self.frame, parentScene.floor.frame)){
    //Colliding with the floor.
}

//Swift
var parentScene : GameScene = self.parent as? GameScene
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(_ rect1: parentScene.floor.frame, _ rect2: self.frame){
    //Colliding with the floor.
}
```

You don't really need to call the `Person` update, you could check the collision in your `GameScene's update:` method, but it's always cleaner to subclass and implement it on the other class (or you will end with a really big update).

Comment: Thank you for your help. It gives me a better idea, although it's like reading Italian to a Spanish speaker...meaning I'm doing it in Swift and this is in Obj-C. :) I appreciate the effort, is there a Swift translation? Either way, I think I know what you're talking about and I'm going to try an idea I got from reading your explanation.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention, as well, that I'm having the character walk on their own (automated animation), so it won't be updating based on my touching the screen.

Comment: I have updated the code with swift version. I could not test the swift code, if there is any error tell me and I will fix it.

Comment: This is very helpful in getting where I need to go! I'll let you know if there are any errors. Thank you.